# Subclass not allowing world to run

Tags: java, class, subclass

I am a beginner, taking a CompSci class in school. This chapter is making subclasses; however, The class is somehow causing the program to terminate. The world doesn't even appear, and there are no errors. (I am running Eclipse).

Here is my code:

```
package karel;
import kareltherobot.*;
public class Race implements Directions
{
public static void main(String args[]) {



class Car extends UrRobot
{   public Car(int street, int avenue, Direction direction, int beepers) 
    {super(5, 5, East, infinity);
    }

    public void turnAround()
    {
        turnLeft();
        turnLeft();
    }

    public void turnRight()
    {   
        turnLeft();
        turnLeft();
        turnLeft();
    }
}
    {   
        World.setVisible(true);
        World.showSpeedControl(true);
    }
        {
            Car kar = (Car) new UrRobot(5, 5, East, infinity);
            kar.move();
            kar.turnLeft();
            kar.move();
            kar.turnAround();
            kar.move();
            kar.turnRight();

        }

}

}
```

Is there a way to get this program to not error to termination?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: You seem to have an empty main() function - your program never seems to execute any of your code because it immediately exits.

Comment: I fixed the empty main() function, yet get an "exception in thread "main"" error.

Comment: The code as shown at this writing defines a class within the main method.  I didn't know that was possible, don't know what it means, and would definitely move it out.  Put the class definition for 'car' outside the brackets enclosing the main method but inside the brackets for the Race class.  If there's still an error, replace all the code above with all the code that doesn't work.

Comment: With most recent edit taken to code, I get this error - "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kareltherobot.UrRobot cannot be cast to karel.Race$1Car
 at karel.Race.main(Race.java:32)".

Answer (score 0):

You need to have code ran in the main function. Java finds and executes code in the classes main function. Try that, if it doesn't work, come back and repost.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
import kareltherobot.*;

public class Race implements Directions
{
    public Race(){
     }

public static void main(String args[]) {

class Car extends UrRobot
{   

public Car(int street, int avenue, Direction direction, int beepers)

{

    super(street, avenue, direction, beepers);
}

public void turnAround()

{
    super.turnLeft();
    super.turnLeft();
}
public void turnRight()
{           
    super.turnLeft();
    super.turnLeft();
    super.turnLeft();
}
}

World.setVisible(true);
World.showSpeedControl(true);    
Car kar = new Car(5, 5, East, 100);
kar.move();
kar.turnLeft();
kar.move();
kar.turnAround();
kar.move();
kar.turnRight();

}
}
```

Comment: Please describe why you think is is an answer. Just posting a wall of code doesn't help much.