# Concurrent Programming. Using Karel the Robot

Tags: java, multithreading, karel

I am in a computer Science class and we have started with using Karel the Robot as the introduction to Java OOP. I want to run two Karel the Robots at the same time, performing two different tasks. I have tried looking up solutions on the internet, and I have been successful in making a working thread, however, I am unable to run two Karel the Robots at the same time. Any help on this Concurrent Programming issue would be appreciated.
Here's the code I have been using:

```
package karel;
import kareltherobot.*;
import kareltherobot.Directions;
import kareltherobot.World;
public class KarelSample implements Directions
{
    public static void main(String [] args)  
    {


          Thread Karelrunner = new Thread();
          Karelrunner.start();
 UrRobot Karel = new UrRobot ( 1,5, North, 2);
 Karel.move();
 Karel.move();
 Karel.putBeeper();
 Karel.turnLeft();
 Karel.move();


}




    static
    {   
    World.setVisible(true);
    World.showSpeedControl(true);



}


    class Karelrunner implements Directions {

        UrRobot Karel2 = new UrRobot(8,8, South, 2);
        Karel2.move();
        Karel2.move();
        Karel2.turnLeft();
        Karel2.turnLeft();
        Karel2.putBeeper();
        Karel2.move();
}



}
```

I have also used the Karel J Robot book's example where the thread setup code would be as follows:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{ ...

Karelrunner r = new Karelrunner();
World.setupThread(r);

  . . .
}
```

Please help in any way you can, I am trying to make a multi-threaded concurrent program. I am new to this and thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232786/subclass-not-allowing-world-to-run#comment16393355_12232786

Comment: No, this is not the same question at all. However, we both have the same CompSci class and are working on different tasks. Please have relevant answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done more research and found a solution to my problem. Thanks kevinsa5 for the idea. For anyone who may have a problem with multi-threading in Karel the Robot or in general, I'll post my code below. Hopefully, it will help in giving you an idea.

```
package karel;
import kareltherobot.*;
import kareltherobot.Directions;
import kareltherobot.World;
public class KarelSample implements Directions
{
    public static void main(String [] args)  
    {
        new Karelrunner(8,8,South,2); 

        UrRobot Karel = new UrRobot (1,3,North,2);

        Karel.move();
        Karel.move();
        Karel.putBeeper();
        Karel.move();
        Karel.turnLeft();
        Karel.move();
    }   

    static
    {   
        World.setVisible(true);
        World.showSpeedControl(true);
    }
}

class Karelrunner extends UrRobot implements Directions 
{
    public Karelrunner (int street, int avenue, Direction direction, int beepers)
    { 
        super ( street, avenue, direction, beepers);
        World.setupThread(this);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        move();
        move();
        putBeeper();
        turnLeft();
        move();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about threading, perhaps looking into setting the delay between actions would be more helpful. Example in pseudocode:

```
create karel_one
create karel_two
while(true){
setdelay(0)
karel_one.act()
karel_two.act()
setdelay(10) // or whatever
}
```

So it would appear as if they are acting concurrently. I did this a few years ago, but (as you can probably imagine) karel the robot isn't very useful outside of the classroom, so I don't remember the specifics. I think the delay method might be a part of World? Not sure.

EDIT: You can also use this idea to create 'instant' functions like turnRight() instead of waiting forever to turn left three times... ugh.